# urllib3.HTTPSConnectionPool Error

Tags: python-2.7, urllib3

I'm trying to request a RestAPI resource multiple times. In order to save time, I try to use urllib3.HTTPSConnectionPool instead of urllib2. However, it keeps throwing me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LCRestapi.py", line 135, in <module>
    listedLoansFast(version, key, showAll='false')
  File "LCRestapi.py", line 55, in listedLoansFast
    pool.urlopen('GET',url+resource,headers={'Authorization':key})
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 515, in urlopen
    raise HostChangedError(self, url, retries)
urllib3.exceptions.HostChangedError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/loans/listing?showAll=false', port=None): Tried to open a foreign host with url: https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/loans/listing?showAll=false
```

I'm using python-2.7.6

Here's my code:

```
manager = urllib3.PoolManager(1)
url = 'https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/loans/listing?showAll=false'
pool = urllib3.HTTPSConnectionPool(url+resource, maxsize=1, headers={'Authorization':key})
r = pool.request('GET',url+resource)
print r.data
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're creating a `PoolManager` but never using it. Instead, you're also creating an `HTTPSConnectionPool` (which is bound to a specific host) and using that instead of the `PoolManager`. The `PoolManager` will automatically manage `HTTPSConnectionPool` objects on your behalf, so you don't need to worry about it.

This should work:

```
# Your example called this `manager`
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

url = 'https://api.lendingclub.com/api/investor/v1/loans/listing?showAll=false'
headers = {'Authorization': key}

# Your example did url+resource, but let's assume the url variable
# contains the combined absolute url.
r = http.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
print r.data
```

You can specify the size for the `PoolManager` if you'd prefer, but you shouldn't need to unless you're trying to do something unusual with limiting resources to a pool of threads.